# Loop through two jQuery objects simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery objects of equal length.

```
var foos = $('.foo');
var bars = $('.bar');
```

If these were arrays, I could loop through them using their index, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++){
    foos[i].html(bars[i].html());
}
```

But referencing jquery objects in this manner returns the node itself, not the specific matched jquery object. This can be fixed like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++){
    $(foos[i]).html($(bars[i]).html());
}
```

but that is not clean/easy to read, and I believe it is inefficient. Is there another way to loop through two jQuery objects simultaneously?

Edit: it IS much less efficient, see > http://jsperf.com/js-array-vs-jquery-selector

Comment: @Brian because he needs to control one for the other inside the loop.

Comment: how do you know that `foos.length === bars.length`?

Comment: @Dmitry because I control the HTML content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++)
{
    foos.eq(i).html(bars.eq(i).html());
}
```

From the Docs:

> **Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Comment: Check out [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/js-array-vs-jquery-selector). Eq is even less efficient than using the workaround I mentioned.

Comment: So why did you bother to ask a question when it seems you've already decided on the right answer?

Comment: @JamesG. Are you having a performance problem you are trying to fix? Otherwise i'd consider that argument null/void.

Comment: I hadn't already decided, but I have been struggling with this for several hours. I'm looking for an answer that is better than the one I already have. Though it is really weird that eq is less efficient... it should at worst be the same as that. Huh.

Comment: @KevinB yes, this is a performance concern when looping over two large arrays of elements.

Comment: Then the best course of action would be to drop jquery and do it with javascript directly, if performance is a concern. This is a relatively simple task in javascript anyway.

Comment: I can not +1 @KevinB's comment above enough!

Comment: @KevinB Would be nice if jQuery was able to do this efficiently, but that is always an option :)

Comment: but jquery IS able to do it! but anything you do in jQuery will always be slower than without jquery.

Comment: jQuery can do it, but if performance is an issue you should remove the overheads it provides.

Answer (score 2):

BenM's answer directly answers this question, but i wanted to provide an alternative.

```
foos.html(function (i) {
   return bars.eq(i).html();
});
```

Not sure if it would be any more effective.

Could of course shorten the inner part to make it more efficient, but i would consider that a micro-optimization that shouldn't be used unless you actually have a performance problem to fix.

```
foos.html(function (i) {
   return bars[i].innerHTML;
});
```

And of course, the javascript version which will always be faster than any js library:

```
for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++){
  foos[i].innerHTML = bars[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```js
foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');

for(var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++){
  foos[i].innerHTML = bars[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar">Hello World!1</div>
<div class="bar">Hello World!2</div>
<div class="bar">Hello World!3</div>
```